# Admin module with as many image slots as user needs?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, module, admin, magento-1

Something I use a fair deal in wordpress is allowing users to duplicate a field, so i provide one image slot and they can click a [+] button and get another image slot.

I'm trying to make a quick blog module and was wondering if there is something similar to this or if I'll just need to build in say 10 image upload slots for the module?

Comment: in order to achieve this you need to create a separate table for the images. You can try to copy the behavior of the image uploader from the product management section, or you can write some js that allows you to add image fields 'on the fly', and save them in the separate table in the controller. (this is just a suggestion not a real answer to your problem).

Answer (score 0):

Just add in X image slots and write a little bit of Javascript to show those rows when needed (ie show N+1 when N is filled).